# Autofac: select implementation of a service based on what can be constructed

Tags: c#, autofac

Let's say I have an `IService` and two implementations `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. Then let's assume that `ServiceA` has `ClassA` parameter in its constructor (among others) and `ServiceB` has `ClassB` parameter. I would then like to:

1. Register services as follow:

```cs
containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<ServiceB>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

2. Register an instance of either `ClassA` or `ClassB` (this is decided in runtime).
3. When some other component wants `IService`, autofac will provide one basing one *what can be constructed*, i.e. if it has a `ClassA` object in repository, it will construct and provide `ServiceA` etc.

How can I achieve that? Note that `ClassA` and `ClassB` do not share common interface.

Comment: Maybe you can search a little https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=autofac+factory . Hope you find what you're looking for.

Comment: I try your case and it seems it is *Autofac* default behavior. See https://gist.github.com/cyrildurand/d21daeaccf1794be390f0074736069cb

Comment: @CyrilDurand it's just a coincidence, Autofac tries to resolve the last registration. Change new ClassB to new ClassA and check what happens.

Comment: I'm confused by the connection between `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` in the question because it says that they don't share a common interface. If the question is which implementation of `IService` will be constructed and `ServiceB` doesn't implement that interface, then how does `ServiceB` fit into the question?

Comment: @ScottHannen `SerivceA` and `ServiceB` *do* share the same interface, i.e. `IService`, but `ClassA` and `ClassB` *do not* share the same interface, their common parent is `object`.

Comment: Thanks, I went a little blind there. So you're resolving `IService`, but the implementation resolved must depend on which one has the necessary dependencies registered so that it can be resolved. What do you mean when you say it's decided at runtime? To clarify/confirm, does that mean you can't determine it at startup? IOW, attempt to resolve both types at startup, and then register whichever one can be resolved as the implementation of `IService`?

Comment: @ScottHannen I can decide it at startup. I don't want to go into details of the original problem, but let's assume that `ClassA` or `ClassB` are objects created by command line parser depending on some switches provided by user. Then it would be nice to register all services and simply activate those possible instead of "copying" if-based logic from command line parser to registration.

Comment: I was starting to answer, but my answer was predicated on the condition that there was no other way to decide other than by seeing what the container could resolve. But you're saying there is another way. Absolutely any other possible way would probably be better than what I was going to suggest. You'd have to build a container, try to resolve types from it, and based on the results build another container. Anything else would probably be better.